# How to set single spacing after punctuation in bibliography section using apacite?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, punctuation, apacite

I am working in `APA6` class option, and with the `apacite` citation package.

I want to have strict single spacing after punctuation / between sentences. In text, I used the `\frenchspacing` command. However, this does not apply to bibliography section.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LaTeX generally already typesets its bibliography without extra space after periods. Indeed `apacite` is no exception, its redefinition of `thebibliography` has `` \sfcode`\.=1000\relax ``, which means that a full stop/period will not trigger the behaviour of `\nonfrenchspacing` to add a bit of space afterwards.

Bibliographies do, however, have the additional command `\newblock`. This command is used to separate larger chunks of information in the bibliography. Traditionally it adds a little bit of extra space between those blocks and allows for extra stretchiness. The default definition of `\newblock` for `apacite` is `\def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}`. As it happens, a `\newblock` after a full stop in the bibliography will roughly have the same visual effect as the additional space after a full stop in `\nonfrenchspacing`.

If you want to get rid of the additional space introduced by `\newblock` you can patch its definition in `\thebibliography`. The effect is quite miniscule though.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}
  {\def\newblock{}}
  {}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  year    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
{\frenchspacing Appleby, H. (1980). \emph{On the importance...}\par}

{\nonfrenchspacing Appleby, H. (1980). \emph{On the importance...}\par}

\cite{appleby}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography without extra <code>\newblock</code> space.]

Here is a direct comparison of the two: Red is the original definition, blue the new one with disabled `\newblock`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The effects are quite minuscule indeed, but enough to be notice by my supervisor, I can assure you!